# TCriticalSection and try __finally block

Tags: c++builder, critical-section, try-finally

What is the best practice (cs is a TCriticalSection)

I have seen this a lot

```
cs->Enter();
try {
}
__finally {
  cs->Leave();
}
```

but why not enter the critical section within the try block? Could it cause any issues?

```
try {
  cs->Enter();
}
__finally {
  cs->Leave();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `Leave()` unless `Enter()` succeeds. If `Enter()` fails, calling `Leave()` could leave the cs in a bad state.  This is generally the same rule you should follow for any code that needs to use `try..__finally` to manage resources.  Allocate/Obtain the resource first, THEN enter the `try` block.  Or else change the code to utilize RAII-based logic instead or using `try..__finally` at all.

Comment: Well this is existing code with a couple of hunderd thousand lines of code where they have loved the use of try __finally so I won't refactor that any time soon :P

Comment: If you don't refactor, you should still correct it. Call `Enter()` outside of the `try`, not inside.

Comment: This is WAY late - but just a couple of thoughts:
1.) This is about using Try-Finally and has nothing to do with critical sections.
2.) Consider if the ENTER method was instead a call to CREATE an object and the LEAVE was instead a call to FREE the object. You do the create BEFORE the TRY because if the create fails (e.g. gets an exception) the object doesn't exist so you can't call Free on the object. Therefore you don't want to do the call to create INSIDE of the Try block.